# What actually IS lambda calculus and how do I actually apply it?

Tags: turing-machines, lambda-calculus, variable-binding

Trying to wrap my head around lambda calculus but am really clueless right now.

First of all, I'm really confused WHAT it's actually supposed to be. I've found these definitions:

> Lambda calculus (also written as λ-calculus) is a formal system in mathematical logic for expressing computation based on function abstraction and application using variable binding and substitution. It is a universal model of computation that can be used to simulate any Turing machine. [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)

> The λ calculus can be called the smallest universal programming
> language of the world. The λ calculus consists of a single
> transformation rule (variable substitution) and a single function
> definition scheme. It was introduced in the 1930s by Alonzo Church as
> a way of formalizing the concept of effective computability. The λ
> calculus is universal in the sense that any computable function can be
> expressed and evaluated using this formalism. It is thus equivalent to
> Turing machines. [[UT Dallas]](https://personal.utdallas.edu/%7Egupta/courses/apl/lambda.pdf)

> The Lambda calculus is an abstract mathematical theory of computation, involving \lambdaλ functions. The lambda calculus can be thought of as the theoretical foundation of functional programming. It is a Turing complete language; that is to say, any machine which can compute the lambda calculus can compute everything a Turing machine can (and vice versa). [[brilliant.org]](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lambda-calculus/)

So depending on who you ask, it's either a **mathematical theorem**, a **turing complete programming language**, or an **abstract model of computation**. I've settled on "useless symbol manipulation game beyond my comprehension", but maybe this will change after I've read the answers to this question.

---

I think I might be able to understand the basic syntax. A function that would normally look like this...

```
doesStuff(x)
{
return x;
}
```

...look like this in λ-notation:

```
doesStuff =: λx.x
```

To now do something with the function in lambda calculus you just write the value behind the expression. Like this:

```
λx.x (y)
```

The variable then get's "bound" (whatever that means) to the variable in the expression in a process named **α-conversion**. Like this:

```
(λx.x) → (λy.y)
```

And then the output is produced in a process called **β-reduction**.

```
(λy.y) → (y)
```

This is the output: y.

So far on the abstraction side of things, but what any of that actually *means*, I still don't really get.

---

Beyond that i don't really understand, how I'm supposed to deal with more complex Lambda terms. All explanations I can find don't go much further then introducing the basic concept, don't provide any further details and don't give any examples. What am I supposed to do when I get hit with stuff like this:

```
λa.(λb.bb)(a(λb.a))
```

or this:

```
λab.b(λcde.c(λfg.g(fd))(λf.e)(λf.f))a
```

What's the significance of brackets here? What do they do? How do I handle multiple expressions in a row?

A concept that ALL explanations introduce as if it was self-explanatory is currying. Lambda expressions per definition are not allowed to take more then one argument (Why?). So what you do instead is you create an abstraction in the place of an expression and that... then does stuff?

**I'm unable to link the mental model that lambda calculus introduces to that of a turing machine. How are they even remotely related?**

I've found this website that introduces diagrams as graphical representation for closed lambda terms: https://tromp.github.io/cl/diagrams.html I don't really understand them, but maybe they could be helpful for an explanation, as a "bridge" for the parts I don't yet understand?

---

Comment: None of your sources claim that $\lambda$ calculus is a mathematical *theorem*. In fact, they all agree that $\lambda$ calculus is a mathematical model for computation, which is equivalent in power to Turing machines.

Comment: You are misintepreting the mathematical part. Wikiepdia says it is a "formal system" but later on you say it is a "mathematical theorem". Those are two completely different things.

Comment: If you want to know more, one way is to pick up some lecture notes. There are many online choices, for example [Selinger](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/papers/lambdanotes.pdf).

Comment: you got the alpha conversion thing wrong.  It's just a mean to state that λx.x is the same as λy.y or λz.z etc : they all are the identity function, just differing by the name of the parameter.  beta reduction is basically performing the "function call". (λx.x)y is the application of argument y to the λx.x function.  That is, you take the body of the function (x here) and replace all occurences of x in it by the argument y. In this example you get y.  Applying y to the identity function returns y... which is what you expected!

Comment: You're throwing together a bunch of broad question here. "Is the lambda calculus to be regarded as a programming language or a mathematical theory" is one question that could be and has already been partially answered here. "How does lambda calculus work and how does it do its job as a theory of computation" is another question that is answered in entire books and not something you can expect to understand in depth by reading the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I suggest you narrow this post down to the first question, and then ask more specific questions about where exactly you're stuck in the calculation examples after having read into it more thoroughly, with proper resources as suggested by one of the commenters.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus that seems like great material, thanks for sharing.